# About javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get below result in the end.

```json
[{x: '10', y: '5'}, {x: '8', y: '4'}]
```

I don't understand why the result get by the following code is

```json
[{x: '8', y: '4'}, {x: '8', y: '4'}]
```

```js
var test =[["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var series = {};
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < test.length ; i++){
  series.x = test[i][0];
  series.y = test[i][1];
  console.log(i);
  console.log(series);
  sample.push(series);
};
console.log(sample);
```

Can you give me some advice on what I lack?

Comment: You'll need to create a new object in each cycle of the loop. What you are currently doing is updating the same object in each loop. Your current results is an array of object references, all to the same object.

Comment: in the loop: `let series = { x: test[i][0], y: test[i][1] };`

Comment: got it, sorry I made a careless mistake. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, consider the 1-liner: `let sample = test.map(a => ({ x:a[0], y:a[1] }));`

Comment: This should work `let sample = test.map(([x,y])) => ({ x, y }));`

Comment: Just `test.map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y }))`

Answer (score 1):

`series` is an object, what you have done in the loop basically change the value of members of `series` twice and push `series` into `sample` array twice.
Since `sample[0]` and `sample[1]` point to the same object, they obviously have the same members, you can verify it with `console.log(sample[0] === sample[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pushing the references of the same object (i.e. series) into the array (i.e. sample) twice. That's why the two elements in the results list looks the same. You may want to make a little change (see below) to get what you want.

```js
var test =[["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var series; /* declare a new variable */
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < test.length ; i++){
  series = {};  /* assign a new object */
  series.x = test[i][0];
  series.y = test[i][1];
  console.log(i);
  console.log(series);
  sample.push(series); /* push the reference of the new object for loop i */
};
console.log(sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @shinobu you are doing a simple mistake you are not clearing the object inside object. I am adding a line to the code and it will solve it

```
var test =[["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var series = {};
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < test.length ; i++){
  series = {};
  series.x = test[i][0];
  series.y = test[i][1];
  sample.push(series);
};
console.log(sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `reduce` from ES6 array methods, you can remove most of the codes and replace it with the below code:

```js
var test =[["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var result = test.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc.push({x: current[0], y: current[1]});
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Let me know if you have any doubts in this ! Happy codiing

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator

```js
var test = [["10", "5"], ["8", "4"]];
var series = {};
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
 series.x = test[i][0];
 series.y = test[i][1];
 sample.push({ ...series });
};
console.log(sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var test = [["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var sample = test.map(([ x, y ]) => ({ x, y }));

console.log(sample);
```

---

---

Regarding your original code, [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705998/about-javascript-array/70710238#comment124996209_70705998), you'll need to create the object inside the loop, so you alter the reference to the first one:

```js
var test =[["10", "5"],["8","4"]];
var sample = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < test.length ; i++){
  var series = {};
  series.x = test[i][0];
  series.y = test[i][1];
  sample.push(series);
};
console.log(sample);
```